# How to read the following example of a vector space? looking for a direct translation to English

Tags: linear-algebra

- The set $V = \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) {\overset{\rm def}{=}}
   \{ f \, | \, f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \}$ of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself endowed with the addition $+$ and the scalar multiplication $\cdot$ defined by
          $$
     \begin{array}{rlll}
      f+g :& \mathbb{R} & \to & \mathbb{R} \\
        &t & \mapsto & f(t) + g(t)
     \end{array}
     \qquad
     \text{and}
     \qquad
     \begin{array}{rlll}
      \alpha \cdot f :& \mathbb{R} & \to & \mathbb{R} \\
          &t & \mapsto & \alpha f(t)
     \end{array}
     $$
          is a vector space.

I'm aware of the meaning conveyed by the statement, however I would appreciate some clarity on the notational front as I'm unsure how to go about reading it (quite literally) in English (as in "the set V which is a function(?) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by...is a vector space").

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that the set of real valued  functions is a vector space under the addition and scalar multiplication

We need to check all the axioms of the vector space.

Comment: hi, thanks for your prompt answer. I'm looking for clarity on the notational front, quite literally. specifically in reading $V = \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) {\overset{\rm def}{=}}
 \{ f \, | \, f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \}$

Comment: Just ignore the formalities of the notations. It simply means the operations are defined on real valued functions

Answer (score 0):

This is the set of all real-valued functions on the real numbers under point-wise addition and scalar multiplication.

$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ says that $f$ is a function that maps real numbers to real numbers.

$\{f|f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\}$ is then the set of all such functions.

$\stackrel{\text{def}}=$ means that the term on the left is defined to mean the term on the right. In this case, it's that $\mathcal F(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ shall mean the same as $\{f|f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\}$.